# Pass a value to an instance variable in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a show action in which I want to pass a value to the view, `quantity: 8` , via the queried instance variable.

Here, the creation of the instance variable:

```
@organizer = Organizer.find(params[:id])
```

I guess I could pass this value by either creating a virtual attribute with `attr_accessor` or by passing a value to `params`.

Assuming I'm right about having these two choices, I have two questions.

**Question 1: Does any of the two ways have clear advantages over the other?**

**Question 2: How would I go about adding this value to the params accessible to the view?**

Comment: Ad. 2 you use Rails 3 or 4?

Comment: The question seems unclear. What is the relationship b/w orgranizer & quantity?

Comment: There is no relationship between organizer and quantity other than a temporary attribute, it's a calulated value I sometimes want to pass to the view.  
The questions are regarding RoR 3.

Comment: Can't you just use @quantity = 8?

Comment: @BroiSatse I guess I could.. :) I just think I've read that we should keep the number of instance variables as low as possible, but maybe I'm wrong about that.

Comment: @FellowStranger Where does your `quantity` value come from?

Comment: I agree that amount of instance variable should be limited, but it is much better to have one more than what you are trying to do. Passing it to params is a bad idea as params varaibale has its purpose to pass data from form to controller, not from controller to view - it would break rails convention. You said that there is no link between organizer and quantity, so adding one to another would break general object-oriented programming rule. New instance variable seems to be the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP said it's good practice to minimize instance variables generated in controller, which is better to be only 1.

So, about how to use `quantity`, I will make decision as follows:

1. If this has nothing to do with model, I will use a helper directly and call this helper in view.
2. If this has something to do with model but no relation to controller, I will make such method in model.
3. If this relates to both model and controller, and the pattern could be only once, I will use one more instance variable. It's not good, but only once, so forgive it.
4. If this relates to both model and controller, but expected to appear more than once, I will use a Presenter or Decorator pattern.

And param would not be in my consideration.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1: Does any of the two ways have clear advantages over the other?**

Approach with params is not a real choice. As said, params are used to pass parameters from view to controller and not vise-versa. The clear advantage is that - that is how it is used by convention.

**Question 2: How would I go about adding this value to the params accessible to the view?**

You don't even try. If you mean by this - to set params and pass it to the view. Use instance variable like `@quantity = 8` or you could set-up global variable or new table for variable values, and then set the @quantity with that value